Jenkins pipeline using OWASP ZAP
I have a Jenkins pipeline to continuously build a Python app in a local environment. This is the code:
pipeline {
    agent any
    
    stages {
        
        stage('Checkout') {
            steps {
                git branch: 'master', url: 'https://github.com/ibon-castro/full-stack-py.git'
            }
        }

        stage('Install dependencies') {
            steps {
                sh '''
                python3 -m venv venv
                bash -c "source venv/bin/activate && pip3 install -r requirements.txt"
                '''
            }
        }

        stage('SAST with Bandit') {
            steps {
                sh '''
                # Install Bandit
                bash -c "source venv/bin/activate && pip3 install bandit"
                
                # Run Bandit
                bash -c "source venv/bin/activate && bandit app.py"
                '''
            }
        }

        stage('SCA with Safety') {
            steps {
                sh '''
                bash -c "source venv/bin/activate && pip3 install safety"
                bash -c "source venv/bin/activate && safety check -r requirements.txt"
                '''
            }
        }

        stage('Deploy') {
            steps {
                sh '''
                # Run the application in the background
                bash -c "source venv/bin/activate && python3 app.py &"
                bash -c "source venv/bin/activate && docker run -t ghcr.io/zaproxy/zaproxy:stable zap-baseline.py -t http://localhost:5000"
                '''
            }
        }
            
        stage('Archive ZAP Report') {
            steps {
                archiveArtifacts artifacts: 'zap-report.html', allowEmptyArchive: true
            }
        }
    }
}

The problem comes when using the OWASP ZAP to do the DAST. I am always getting the same error: Automation plan failures:
Job spider failed to access URL http://localhost:5000 : Connect to http://localhost:5000 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
2024-09-19 12:42:30,258 Failed to access summary file /home/zap/zap_out.json
I have also (unsuccesfully) tried to use the standalone zap.

Add --add-host=host.docker.internal:host-gateway to your docker command and use host.docker.internal instead of localhost
docker run -t --add-host=host.docker.internal:host-gateway ghcr.io/zaproxy/zaproxy:stable zap-baseline.py -t http://host.docker.internal:5000


Still getting a similar error:
[33mPress CTRL+C to quit[0m
Using the Automation Framework
Automation plan failures:
Job spider failed to access URL http://host.docker.internal:5000 : Connect to http://host.docker.internal:5000 [host.docker.internal/172.17.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
Maybe you should know that I am running the jenkins in an ubuntu machine in the Multipass app

Add a curl http://localhost:5000 between launching the application and running docker - see if your application is actually up and listening to that port.

We have a FAQ for that :) https://www.zaproxy.org/faq/why-cant-zap-connect-to-my-website/
